# Is it a good or bad idea throwing Exceptions when validating data?

Tags: validation, exception

When validating data, I've gotten into a habit of doing the following:

**Note:** I don't really have individual booleans for each check. This is just for the example.

**Another Note:** any error handling during the tests are done properly. The ONLY exceptions thrown in the try-catch are my own.

```
try {
  if (validCheckOne = false) {
    throw new Exception("Check one is bad");
  }
  if (validCheckTwo = false) {
    throw new Exception("Failed because of check2");
  }
  if(validCheckTen = false) {
    throw new Exception("Yet another failure on your part: check10.");
  }
} catch(Exception e) {
  MessageBox.Show("Your stupid data is wrong! See for yourself: " + e.Message);
}
```

Is this bad practice? Does throwing Exceptions slow the program's execution or is inadvisable?

Comment: You mean validCheckOne == false etc. right?  otherwise you arent getting past the first if statement

Comment: @nashwan, I think you've missed the point of the question.

Comment: nope, was just highlighting did you really mean validCheckTwo = false etc.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Personally I like throwing Exceptions for business rule validation (not so much for user input validation) because it forces the problem to be handled upstream. If my business objects returned some kind of validation result, it could be ignored by the caller. Call me a cowboy if you wish :)

Everyone here is repeating the phrase "exceptions are for exceptional circumstances", but that really doesn't give any understanding of why its bad to use them for unexceptional circumstances. I need more than that. Is the performance hit of throwing exceptions really that bad? Are there any benchmarks available?

Comment: This best marks what i originally intended. 'Exceptional circumstances in the business rules' being apart from simple data validation (startDate before endDate and whatnot), forcing execution upstream.
My problem is that i got into the habit of doing this for *all* my validation (granted, i need to correct this).

Apart from the 'exceptional circumstances' argument, Can anyone show that throwing an exception has a bad effect on the stack? more memory usage or slower execution for example?

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6828204/618281) answer describes why it is bad to use them for unexceptional circumstances. In short it forces you to handle exceptions, now you have to distinguish between a SQL exception and a validation exception. I wouldn't be concerned about performance as much as maintainability of your validation framework.

Comment: It is intuitive for application programmers to get used to just a couple of specific exceptions and use them as appropriate instead of making a mess of various self-invented return codes or even strings. I like the idea of having exception handlers somewhere upstream, and these handlers do their job - log critical errors to database, send e-mails to sysadmins, show meaningful messages to end-users etc. Server-side data validation also could be considered an exception for modern web applications because basic input validation usually can be done in Javascript.

Comment: *"Exceptions are for exceptional circumstances"* is such a misunderstood quote in my opinion. Your operation **can't continue** because a business rule is not met, how is that not exceptional to so many people?

Comment: Thanks for a little bit of pragmatism in this world <3

Comment: Validation should be separated from command. The first one is just checking if the data is valid before it will change the state of the system and therefore should only return validation result. The other one is actually changing the state of the system and should receive validated data. That is good moment to throw exception when validated data is not valid anymore due to other changes in the system.

Comment: I can't see the point to use specific Exception native concepts for doing this. I always considered exceptions for developers and error messages as requirements not attended from business pointview. If somehow, programming languages supporters decides to increment Exceptions with more information, your business validations concepts will receive this new (and not so useful) release. I created a program for testing (https://dotnetfiddle.net/CvLEhV) and using Exceptions got me the worst results, ok, yeah, I forced a little bit but which developer works without expecting worst scenarios?

Comment: The distinction between "user" and "business rule" validation is important.  I would call the example case user input since it shows a messagebox. Two problems for using exceptions for validation in .NET:  First, throwing them causes .NET to unwind the stack trace and tack on other info.  throw ValidationException() is always going to be slower than return BadValidationResult(...). Second, you typically can only throw one at a time.  In the question, the user would get one error, fix, get the next, fix, etc. instead of getting one message "Please fix the following: ..."

Answer (score 34):

I'm going to repeat the mantra here:  throwing exceptions should be done in exceptional circumstances.  Invalid entered data is really not that exceptional.

Comment: Likewise agreeing. Having a program halt, or otherwise bog down because of bad data is a bad idea: skip it and move on. Mind you, it's good to let the user know that there was bad data found; maybe generate a report or pipe it to STDOUT or something something.

Comment: Typical StackOverflow: work your butt off answering difficult, interesting questions, and then get most of your rep points from being the first person to rattle off some simplistic rule. Sigh.

Comment: what if .. your validation is deeply nested and spread over several classes?

Comment: I never agreed with this mantra, especially in a language like Java with checked exceptions (where you can force the caller to handle your exception). The alternative would be to return an error and roll an error handler into the caller. Why would you choose to implement a custom error handler over getting a well implemented one for free in the language that not only likely better than what you would do, but gives you (in a language with checked exceptions) compiler enforcement

Comment: Disagree, sometimes a user entering something CAN break a business rule (not all user input validation is about checking they entered a valid email address etc.).  In which case throw an exception in your application code, handle it and then show up a validation error from it.

Comment: It's a play on words, I have yet to read any convincing argument for why is should be the case. Using exceptions and catching them can really clean up code, especially in multi layered systems.

Comment: Another case when exceptions cannot be used: there are not errors during the validation but there are warnings or information (you have to write special handler).

Comment: @Blauohr then you've lost track of the SOLID principles

Comment: this is badly assuming validation is only for data being "entered" it could very well be you are working in a web service, and invalid data is truly exceptional, and should be treated as such... I thought the question was more interesting in semantics, like, an assert must throw an exception if the condition fails, by semantics, do we have a similar understanding for validation? should it return true or false or throw an exception? there does not seem to be an answer to this

Answer (score 26):

I support MusiGenesis's answer.

Additionally...

---

The **performance** of throwing an exception is a thousand instructions. It's nothing compared to end-user time, but in inner code it is slow.

An additional problem is that, using Exceptions, **your validation is limited to reporting the first failure** (and you will have to do it all again next time to find the next failure).

Comment: The last point is incorrect. You can do all your validation and save all error messages in a custom validation object (or C# `ValidationResult `). Then you can throw a custom exception (or C# `ValidationException`) which contains the custom validation object (`ValidationException(ValidationResult, ValidationAttribute, Object)`).

Answer (score 18):

In addition to the oft-repeated statement that "exceptions are for exceptional circumstances", here's an additionally clarifying rule I've come to like:

> If the user caused it, it's not exceptional.

Exceptions are for system-side things (servers going down, resources being unavailable), not for the user doing odd things, because all users do odd things.

Comment: But what if I have some basic validation in my web application on client side (web browser)? Couldn't then server side validation be treated as exceptional? It is normally not expected user to bypass Javascript validation, thus why bother with using multiple error codes, weird loops with breaks, `if`s and what not, if it is so tempting to throw `DataValidationException` which then will be displayed to the user as some generic message "Wrong value for field X".

Comment: This is the same question I'm pondering. Build up all the errors in a list and throw an exception with all of them. Then you can have a generic way to handle them and you only write it once. Otherwise the coder has to handle the response for every call duplicating code and possibility of missing the check.

Answer (score 8):

In the title you call it "validating" data. That can happen on several levels. In (near) the GUI where you are checking user entered data, you should be expecting errors and have ways to report the errors back. Exceptions are inappropriate in this case.

But Data Validation can also happen at other boundaries, say between business-rule classes. There, errors in the data are uncommon and unexpected. You should throw when you detect one.

Comment: Are you writing about something like "validating the parameters for a public method" ?

Answer (score 7):

It depends - if you are expecting the data to be there and NOT having the data is unexpected, then throwing an exception is OK.  Throwing an exception is very expensive (slow) but is the best way to handle unexpected circumstances.

Answer (score 4):

So maybe in some languages exception throwing and catching is "costly" but in other languages, throwing and catching exceptions is exactly what's called for.

In Smalltalk, for example, one could quickly build a multi-tiered exception catching solution.  The validation pass could collect up any number of exceptions representing EVERYTHING that's wrong with a particular input data set.  Then it would throw them ALL up to a higher-level catcher, responsible for formatting up a human-readable explanation of, again, EVERYTHING that was wrong with the input.  In turn it would throw a single exception further up the chain, along with that formatted explanation.

So... I guess what I'm saying is, exceptions are only bad to throw if you've got no exception handling architecture supporting catching them and doing reasonable things with them, and all your catcher is going to do is EXIT or do something else equally inappropriate.

Comment: I completely agree. Another example is OCaml. Ocaml supports very light weight exceptions, foregoing things like generating stack traces, thus making it perfectly acceptable (and commonplace) to use as a control-flow mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that using exceptions as described in the question (for flow control within a function) is <strike>wrong</strike> not usually the best idea. I'd go further and saying validation *throwing* exceptions isn't the best approach; instead return a Boolean and store a list of validation error messages that can be accessed. An accompanying save method could/should throw an exception if it is called on an invalid object.

Thus if validate fails validation error messages can be displayed to the user (logged, returned. whatever). If validation passes then you can call save.
If you call save on an invalid object then get get an appropriate exception.

Another potential problem with your example code (depending on requirements of course) is it only throws the first validation error that occurs. Imagine this from a users POV:

- Click save
- Get an error message
- Correct error
- Click save again
- Get a different error message. *Annoying.*

As a user I'd prefer to get all validation errors returned at once so I can correct them all before trying again.

Answer (score 1):

This is bad behavior.  Exceptions are for *Exceptional* conditions.  They take resources to generate the stack etc.  Exceptions should not be used to dictate process flow.

Comment: Err, that's exactly what exceptions do. They are a form of flow control, taking a value along with them.

Answer (score 1):

In general it is inadvisable to use Exceptions to implement conditional flow. It would be better to do something like this

```
  error = false;
  while(true) {
    if(validCheckOne == false) { 
       msg = "Check one is bad"; 
       error = true;
       break;
    }

    if(validCheckTwo == false) { 
       msg = "Check two is bad"; 
       error = true;
       break;
    }
    ...
    break;
  }
  if (error) {
     ..
  }
```

You should throw an exception when there is a situation you can't do nothing about it. Higher layers of software would have a chance to catch the exception and do something about it - even if that is simply crashing the application.

Comment: Why is there a while loop?  If there are no errors this will spin forever.

Comment: I guess the loop is used to easily break the validation once an error has been detected. But you are right, when there are no errors, a final break in the while loop is needed. Maybe it would be better to put the checks into an own method which returns the error message. Apart from these issues I would vote for this answer.

Comment: @Philip Davis: You are right about the infinite loop. I forgot a break at the end.

Comment: Don't ever use while(true), if someone comes along and edits whats inside the loop you are probably gonna get infinite loop bugs.

Answer (score 1):

I generally agree with the "exceptions should be exceptional" rule, but I might make an exception (ha!) for Python, where it can be both efficient and considered good practice to use try ... except to control flow.

See [Using Exceptions For Other Purposes](http://diveintopython.net/file_handling/index.html#d0e14344), for example.

Answer (score 1):

This question is still interesting, mainly because of the answers.

When it comes to exception, there is a lot of arguments involved. We can defend a point to any direction we want to, from performance to exception philosophy. And they all sounds right to me.

But sometimes we have to stick to a direction. In this case, I think it's the validation itself.

When we want to validate something we also want to know (to log, or to show the user) whats wrong when the parameter is invalid. Even thought there are layers of validation such as Business Validation mixed with User Input validations.

For instance, when dealing with user input, a lot of weird cases can happen. A pasted data from a website full of hidden char (\t \n etc), typos, and a really huge kinds of cases that a specific exception could allow further analysis or message to the uses much more precisely than a simple "false" return.

Answer (score 1):

Well, i know it's an old question. But i'll let my opinion here for the googler's who falled here like me:

1. If you are using a language with a bad try/catch support **AVOID
   THROWING** exceptions for data validation;
2. **DO NOT THROW** a exception that will not be handled by the caller or
   alserwhere;
3. **DO NOT THROW** a exception if you need to validate the rest of the received data;
4. You can **THROW** a exception in cases where the code block cannot continue
   without the invalid data; And if you do not interrupt the process you
   can get a unhandled exception;

An example:

```js
/*
 * Here it's a common problem i have: Someone pass a list of products i need to
 * retrieve from the database and update some information;
 */

//This is a class to represent the product
function Product(id, name, price) {
 this.id = id;
 this.name = name;
 this.price = price;
}

//This is an example function to retrieve the product from the database
function findProductInDatabase(productId) {

 //If the product exists on the database, the function will return it
 if (productId == 12) {
  var product = new Product(12, "Book", 20.5);
  return product;
 }
 
 //If the product do not exists, it will return null
 return null;
}

//This is a function that will receive the productID and will update the received parameters
function updateProduct(productId, newProductName, newProductPrice) {

 var productFromDatabase = null;
 var errorMessage = "";
 
 //Retrieve the product
 productFromDatabase = findProductInDatabase(productId);

 //If the product do not exist, i need to interrupt de method imediatily and alert the caller
 if (!productFromDatabase) {
  throw "Product not found";
 }
 
 //Validate the other parameters, but in this case i can validate all the parameters
 if (newProductPrice < 10) {
  errorMessage += "the price is too low";
 }
 
 if (newProductName.includes("<")) {
  
  //If already has a error message in the variable i append " and " to the message make sense
  if (errorMessage) {
   errorMessage += " and ";
  }
  
  errorMessage += "the new name has invalid characters";
 }
 
 if (errorMessage) {
  //if theres any error, i will throw a exception with the messages
  throw errorMessage;
 }
}

//This parte is where the method id called;
try {
 updateProduct(9, "Book", 10.5);
} catch (exception) {
 console.log("Case 1: " + exception);
}
try {
 updateProduct(12, "<Book", 9);
} catch (exception) {
 console.log("Case 2: " + exception);
}
```

Comment: what do you mean with "bad try/catch support"? "will not be handled by the caller" the caller should normally handle exceptions, but yeah if you are forbidden from using them then you shouldn't, although it *could* be a sign of bad code

Answer (score 1):

When you go to the grocery and ask the seller if he's got cheese, and the seller replies with no, would that be an unexpected or exceptional response?
What about if you do the same but the seller just looks at you and does not respond!

Another example, you are talking to your friend and ask if there is something wrong, you may get 2 responses:

- They tell you that they are sad because of something.
- Or they just look at you and say nothing, turn their back and walk away and you are sure that this means you're in deep trouble :)

Same way with exceptions, unexpected behavior is an exception, but an invalid but expected response should not - IMHO - throw exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

I often write similar code for validation, especially in express.js, and similar request/response loop style applications. When something is invalid, I throw a ValidationError, it's caught by the top level error handler, which knows to send a 422 response with the additional information that's attached to the ValidationError.

It's a very convenient way to handle validation. You don't have to pass around an error object (potentially up through a dozen stack frames, in some cases). And it's a simple and consistent way to trigger an invalid input response. I haven't experienced any serious problems with this approach.

I've thought about the "don't use exceptions for flow control" maxim in relation to this practice, and decided the benefits outweigh any disadvantages. I would say if you understand the reasoning behind "don't use exceptions for flow control", but you determine that it's a good idea *anyway* in a certain case, then go ahead and do it. We don't need to be too dogmatic about these things.

Throwing exceptions is relatively slow, but that will only matter if you're doing it repeatedly in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

It really only matters if your data validation is in a tight loop.  For most cases, it doesn't matter what you choose as long as you are *consistent* in your code.

If you have a lot of code that looks like your sample above then you might want to clean it up by introducing a helper method to throw...

```
private void throwIf( bool condition, String message )
{
    if( condition )
        throw new ApplicationException( message );
}
```

(also, doing this will help zero in on errors such as "validCheckOne = false" versus "validCheckOne == false"  :)

Answer (score 0):

In test, sure, but in a live environment, you'd hope they're never raised.
You'd hope to refactor your code to the extent that all data into your system are validated at source, and either the user, or the system that generated the input to your system, is notified of the issue.
Exceptions should occur if you've missed something and should be a fallback that is handled gracefully.
You could store anything that's causing these exceptions separately, so that they don't make it into your system without being checked over first.
You don't want, e.g. an invalid value that falls outside a range of values to skew your results.

Answer (score 0):

I think the currently accepted answer here is wrong. The example given is user input validation, and throwing an exception is not good way to handle for a few reasons:

- the stack trace will be unwound and other info added to the exception.  Any benchmark or perf tool will show this is slower than, say, "return validationErrors"
- you can typically only throw one exception at a time.  In the example, the user would get an error, fix, get the second error, fix, get the third.  Had it returned all 3 errors to the user, they could have fixed all 3 at once.  In a real world scenario this would mean 3 less api calls, db trips, etc.  3x faster to get the user input to a valid state. There may be cases where you can't do validation2 until validation1 is fixed, but exceptions *force* you to only do one at a time in all cases.
- In a web api scenario, result codes matter.  Exceptions typically return a 500 "server error", where you really should be returning a 400 "bad request" and some details the client can do something with.
- In logs and analytics, validation errors can appear as noise, hiding exceptional exceptions.  You typically care about SQL dbs timing out, api endpoints failing, etc., not Joe typing in an invalid amount.

Given this I think a better solution in OPs case is:

```
  var validationErrors = new List<string>();
  if (validCheckOne = false) 
    validationErrors.Add("Check one is bad");
  
  if (validCheckTwo = false) 
    validationErrors.Add("Failed because of check2");
  
  if(validCheckTen = false) 
    validationErrors.Add("Yet another failure on your part: check10.");
  
  if(validationErrors.Count > 0) 
    MessageBox.Show("Please fix the following:" string.Join(",",validationErrors));
  else SomeProcessing(input);
```

This would certainly be faster, both in CPU time and user's time fixing the problem(s). In a scenario where the caller is expected to already have done user input validation like above, throwing exceptions might make sense.  To continue the example, assuming there is a risk that SomeProcessing() could be called by *other* code where the developer forgot to do user input validation, something like this may be needed:

```
void SomeProcessing(input){
   var validationErrors = Validate(input);
   if (validationErrors.Count > 0) throw new ValidationException("The input is not valid.  Developers should prevent this exception by first calling Validate() to validate the input.");
}
```

However, this means validation logic gets called twice- once for user input and again as a guard clause or business rule.  So, what I land on is having business logic able to return either validation errors or a successful result:

```
var result = SomeProcessing(input)
if (result.ValidationErrors.Count > 0)MessageBox.Show("Please fix the following:" string.Join(",",result.ValidationErrors));

...

ValidationErrorsOrResult SomeProcessing(input){
 var result = new ValidationErrorsOrResult();
 if (validCheckOne = false) 
    result.ValidationErrors.Add("Check one is bad");
  
  if (validCheckTwo = false) 
    result.ValidationErrors.Add("Failed because of check2");
  
  if(validCheckTen = false) 
    result.ValidationErrors.Add("Yet another failure on your part: check10.");
  
  if(validationErrors.Count > 0) return result;
  
  result.Result = ...;
  return result;
   
}
```

What 'ValidationErrorsOrResult' looks like will depend on what you're doing.  It could be a simple array of string like here, or more complex - indicating field(s) that are invalid.

Finally, the example is for a desktop app, but in a web api, one should return a 400 with the validation problems, and some specs are forming around "[Problem Details](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9457.html#name-detail)" for doing that:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult SomeApiEndpoint(SomeInput input){
   var result = SomeProcessing(input);
   if(result.ValidationErrors.Count > 0)
   {
       AddValidationErrorsToModelState(result)
       return BadRequest(ModelState);
   }
   return Ok(result.Result);

}
```

With this approach, user input is validated more quickly, users can get more than one validation problem handled at once, and exceptions are saved for truly exceptional things like the database being down, 3rd party api failing, scenarios we didn't forsee, etc.