# Should a validate method throw an exception?

Tags: python, validation, exception, error-handling

I've implemented a little validation library which is used like this:

```
domain_object.validate()

# handle validation errors in some way ...
if domain_object.errors:
    for error in domain_object.errors:
        print(error)
```

`validate()` performs the checks and populates a list called `errors`.

I know from other validation libraries that they throw exception when validation is performed unsuccessfully. Error messages would be passed as an exception property.

What approach is better? Is it advantageous to throw validation exceptions?

Comment: Important to get those language-specific tags in there earlier, rather than later. A lot of programming problems, particularly those concerned with "best practices", will get different answers depending on the language that you're using. I assumed that was pseudo-code or that the language didn't matter. When that's the case in the future, please add the `[language-agnostic]` tag.

Comment: The question was meant to be language agnostic - and I still think it should be language agnostic. I've added the "python" tag only because my example is written in Python.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, I wouldn't think that a validation method should throw an exception.

That would create a bit of an anti-pattern, as the client code calling the method would reasonably *expect* an exception to be thrown, and would then need to catch the exception. Since it's generally recommended that exceptions not be used for flow control, why not just return a value indicating whether validation was successful or not. The client code could check the return value and proceed accordingly.

You essentially accomplish the same thing as you would by throwing an exception, but without the extra cost and poor semantics of actually throwing an exception.

Exceptions should be reserved for truly *exceptional* conditions, not normal operation of a program. Failing validation to me seems like it is a pretty normal condition, something to be *expected* during the day-to-day operation of an application. It would be easily handled by the calling code, and normal operation would continue. Generally, that's not the case with exceptions.

Comment: I'd hardly second such affirmation when programming in Python. While it is true for most language communities, Python developers tend to follow the [EAFP principle](http://tinyurl.com/PyEAFP). It is so widespread in the language that even native, syntax-supported structures follow this principle - see e.g. the [`StopIteration` exception](http://tinyurl.com/StopIteration) which marks the end of iterators and about which even the `for` loop is aware. So, yes, the use of exceptions for flow control and validation is a recommended and widespread idiom in Python.

Comment: Yes, the Python tag was added long after I composed and submitted my answer. This was a more generic answer not assuming any particular language or implementation of extensions. I know nothing about Python, so my advice should be taken with a grain of salt when it comes to that language *in particular*. Otherwise, I'm not deleting this because it's good general advice about the semantics of exceptions.

Comment: Oh, now I understand. In fact, I'd agree that your answer is good in the broader, language-agnostic sense. I bet it is a good collaboration for the question anyway, although not the specific answer for it.

Comment: My thought was, that this problem is language agnostic.

Comment: @deamon: I thought the same... but Brandizzi makes a good argument for why Python is [may be] different. The overriding rule is to follow the standard and accepted idioms of your language. Mine is definitely dogma for C++ and the .NET languages, but that may not apply in alternative worlds.

Comment: @brandizzi I'm not sure whether EAFP ("optimistic coding") is applicable here. The intention behind this principle seems to be to avoid checks that usually don't fail (call a method and assume it exists ...). But in the case of input validation it is not unusual to have invalid values.

Answer (score 7):

I argue for the exact opposite: In a validation layer you want to ensure that every validation error is handled. If you rely on return values, there might be a bug in the integration code (especially when you use the validators in a different environment).

Python exceptions will make that problem obvious.

Comment: I recently encountered an error like this where errors in validation were failing to be reported because nobody was bothering to handle the return.  Who knows how long it has been like that.