# C# - don't break a try catch block

Tags: c#, .net, try-catch

I want to set values that I read from a database to strings (using a **SqlDataReader**). I have a **try-catch** block to catch some System.DBNull that may come from the database table. And whenever those *nulls* appear I want to set a different value to that field. Those fields are then to be set to an object and then added to a list.

The following code demostrates better my problem:

```cs
while (reader.Read())
{
    try
    {
        string originalfilename = (string)reader[0];
        string renamedfilename = (string)reader[1];
        string sheet = (string)reader[2];
        string version = (string)reader[3];

        AddDocument(originalfilename, renamedfilename, sheet, version);
    }
    catch (InvalidCastException e)
    {
        e.Source = "N/A";
    }
}
```

In the example, if **reader[2]** is System.DBNull then I want that the **sheet** string to have *"N/A"*, but I want **version** to be set normally from **reader[3]** and AddDocument executed after.

I am looking for a solution without many *if's*. I thought that *e.Source* would solve my problem but the **try** block breaks after the exception is caught.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should only use exceptions when the case you're working with is an exception, something you can't really deal with "now". You should use `if`s or ternary expressions.

Comment: Are you sure you should be using a try/catch block? It sounds like this isn't necessarily *exceptional* behavior.

Comment: You'd need a try/catch per field. Using an `if(... != DbNull)` is so much better in every way.

Comment: What @HenkHolterman said... having an `if` for each field is easier than a `try/catch` for each field

Comment: @Mephy Correct, that serves as a lesson to avoid using exceptions if I want a normal work-flow of the program, like pointed out in another answer.

Comment: Also see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1504343/60761)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use exceptions like this, exceptions are for exceptional circumstances. You have to define a method that returns a default value if it's parameter is DbNull:

```
private T GetValueOrDefault<T>(object val, T defaultValue)
{
    if(val == DBNull.Value)
        return defaultValue;
    return (T)val;
}
```

Then you can use this method like this:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    string originalfilename = GetValueOrDefault<string>(reader[0], "N/A");
    string renamedfilename = GetValueOrDefault<string>(reader[1], "N/A");
    string sheet = GetValueOrDefault<string>(reader[2], "N/A");
    string version = GetValueOrDefault<string>(reader[3], "N/A");

    AddDocument(originalfilename, renamedfilename, sheet, version);
}
```

Comment: @Blam No, it won't fail. Why do you think it's going to fail ?

Comment: OK I guess if you read into object it will work.  I still think my answer is way cleaner.

Comment: Excellent, it works perfectly and liked the simplicity. @Blam it won't fail, the test is always done and I'm always expecting a real value or a DBNull.

Answer (score 2):

Simple approach:

```
var sheet = reader[2] as string ?? "N/A"
```

or use an extension method:

```
    public static class DataReaderExtensions 
    {
        public static T Read<T>(this SqlDataReader reader, int index, T defaultValue = default(T))
        {
            var value = reader[index];

            return (T)((DBNull.Value.Equals(value))
                       ? defaultValue
                       : Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(T)));
        }
    }
```

and use it like that:

```
while(myDataReader.Read())
{
  string sheet = myDataReader.Read<string>(2, "n/a");
}
```

Comment: @Michael he is talking about the null-coalescence operator `??`, not the nullable shortcut `?`. But this doesn't answer also, because OP is looking for `DBNull` and not `null`.

Comment: It works coz because .NET is unable to cast it and assigns a NULL , that is why you have to use "as" for the cast. The answer from Loures simply using ?? does not work however.

Comment: index can't be null - it is an int

Comment: OK with var I guess it will work but I think rdr.IsDBNull(2) ? "N/A" : reader.GetString(2) of my answer is way cleaner and faster

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `try-catch` for normal work-flow, instead you should use [`reader.IsDBNull`:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.isdbnull(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
string originalfilename = reader.GetString(0);
string renamedfilename = reader.GetString(1)
string sheet = null;
if(reader.IsDBNull(2))
    sheet = "N/A";
else
     sheet = reader.GetString(2);
string version = reader.GetString(3)
```

Comment: There's no `e` in this context. You probably mean `string sheet = reader.IsDBNUll(2) ? "N/A" : reader.GetString(2);`

Comment: Look at his catch-block. It declares the captured exception as `e`. There's no `e` in the `try` scope.

Comment: IsDBNull is indeed useful, however what I wanted was not only to the sheet field, but for general purpose. I have like 15 fields and needed a way to know which was going to fail.

Answer (score 0):

I think the [?: operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) is the most direct approach.

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    string originalfilename = reader.GetString(0);
    string renamedfilename = (string)reader[1];
    string sheet = rdr.IsDBNull(2) ? "N/A" : reader.GetString(2);;
    string version = (string)reader[3];
    AddDocument(originalfilename, renamedfilename, sheet, version);
}
```

to be safe (and simple)

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    AddDocument(rdr.IsDBNull(0) ? "N/A" : reader.GetString(0)
               ,rdr.IsDBNull(1) ? "N/A" : reader.GetString(1)
               ,rdr.IsDBNull(2) ? "N/A" : reader.GetString(2)
               ,rdr.IsDBNull(3) ? "N/A" : reader.GetString(3));
}
```

Comment: Instead of break, you would be better off with an else.

Comment: @ChuckBuford OK I agree.  I was thinking the catch would exit.

Comment: prehaps `continue` could also work if other processing were necessary

Comment: Why are you setting `e.Source`? You haven't caught the Exception

Comment: @eddie_cat Agree.  Why is the question setting e.Source if it is not rethrowing the exception?

Comment: @Blam I did not rethrow because what I had in mind was switch the "bad" value to "N/A".

Comment: That is not what a catch does.  Really you would rather use an extension method than a call to to IsDBnull and ?: operator?

Comment: @Blam No. I just thought that could be a work around to avoid a lot of if's. IsDBNull is indeed useful and I like the simplicity of your solution. Since I am working with many fields I prefered the extension method answered above.

Comment: "rdr.IsDBNull(0) ? "N/A" : reader.GetString(0);"  is two characters different than "GetValueOrDefault<string>(reader[0], "N/A");" with the same number of parameter, no extension method, and is more efficient.

Comment: @Blam Thank you then, I will reconsider :). Most answers work so I had to choose.

Comment: Which works best?  I do this for a living my answer is the most efficient.  Why in the world would you load to object to test for null then cast to string?   IsDBNull is the fastest way to check for null.  And GetString is the fastest way to cast to string.