# Is user tampering data using DOM manipulation an Exceptional Circumstance?

Tags: java, validation, exception

I am currently reading some best practices in exception handling (Java specifically).

I've read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504302/is-it-a-good-or-bad-idea-throwing-exceptions-when-validating-data).

I get it that throwing exceptions is only for ***exceptional circumstances*** but for example:

In my view, I have 2 dropdowns and Parent and Child dropdowns. Values of Child dropdown are dependent on what is selected in Parent dropdown.

In my backend validation I should be expecting `parent.id.equals(child.parentId)` right? But what if this is not the case because the user tampered the data by submitting a valid Child value but just not under the selected parent?

Is this considered an ***exceptional circumstance that permits me, by convention, to throw an Exception***?

Comment: User tampering of any form is exceptional by definition. Don't get too hung up on this 'exceptional circumstance' business propagated by the exception police. The fact is that exceptions are just another mechanism, to be used or abused. You throw an exception when doing so is the best option. Sometimes it is the only option, and this may be just such a case.

Comment: This indicates either 1) a bug; or 2) hacking attempt. In both cases an exception is warranted and certainly your backend should not perform the standard action. Ideally, you should get full debug information in testing environment and none on production frontend (but in the background a warning in the logs is useful, as an alert about potential hacking attempt).