# C# Form App - stop execution of all code from a helper method that resides in a helper class

Tags: c#

I just learned how to pass arguments into methods, so I'm refactoring my code to make it cleaner. I have created a new "ValidateInput" class which holds a ValidateFinancialsInput method which I pass a string into. It then checks the string to see if it is correct, if it's not I want to show a messageBox, then stop execution of ALL of the code. If i use "return;", it just resumes execution of the Parent method. How do I stop execution of all of the code within the ValidateFinancialsInput method? I tried researching this for a while to no avail. Here is my code:

```
Class Parent
{    
   private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {     var CompanyVar = comboBox1.Text;

            ValidateInput vi = new ValidateInput();
            vi.ValidateFinancialsInput(CompanyVar);
             //the rest of my code for the application is here
             //the rest ...
              //the rest...
      }
}

class ValidateInput
{

    public void ValidateFinancialsInput(string Co)
    {
        string[] validCompany = { "BVV", "LWDO" };
        if (validCompany.Contains(Co) == false)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You have entered an invalid company.");
           //what do I put here to stop all code execution?
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: If it's a `Commandline` program, just use `Console.readLine();`

Comment: Using a MessageBox there will make the code untestable by unit tests. That validation is business logic, not UI stuff. Do UI stuff in the UI.

Comment: @ThomasWeller good stuff. Thank you

Comment: @ThomasWeller and by do UI stuff in the UI you're saying do the MessageBox in the main button2_click function correct?

Comment: @JaAustin: yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try and use return values state intent to calling methods

```
Class Parent
{    
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {     var CompanyVar = comboBox1.Text;

        ValidateInput vi = new ValidateInput();
        if(!vi.ValidateFinancialsInput(CompanyVar))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You have entered an invalid company.");
            return;
        }
         //the rest of my code for the application is here
         //the rest ...
          //the rest...
  }
}

class ValidateInput
{

 public bool ValidateFinancialsInput(string Co)
 {
    string[] validCompany = { "BVV", "LWDO" };
    if (validCompany.Contains(Co) == false)
    {
       return false;
    }
    return true;

 }
}
```

What I'm doing here is returning a true|false value to indicate whether the validation has passed, if it has not passed then I display the MessageBox, else it continues the execution of the "other" code.

Hope this helps

Comment: It helps but it doesn't really make the code cleaner. It seems like it kind of defeats the purpose of creating a new class and method to handle the validation .

Comment: I apologies but I disagree, this makes the code significantly cleaner, it keeps visual code in one class whilst keeping validation (not a visual concern) in another class. This significantly helps separate the two concerns which can now change independently. You should check out the SOLID principles (https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/703634/SOLID-architecture-principles-using-simple-Csharp)

Comment: Thanks for the article. does your code validate the S (single responsibility principle)in solid? If the main function 1) calls other functions and 2) checks their output, that's 2 things .  Am I thinking about this correctly ? Maybe I should have another function whose sole purpose is to check other functions' output

Comment: This is a common misconception, the S in solid doesn't mean "a function can only do one thing" it is supposed to be thought about in another sense, "A method or class should only have one reason to change" so in your case, If I wanted to change the logic around the UI of this screen I would have to know that ValidateInput does UI based actions and would possibly need to change. Say for example I had another screen that needed the same validation but didn't need a message box what would I do? The man himself (Bob Martin) talking about his principles https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TMuno5RZNeE

Comment: I used your setup to validate 3 inputs, company, year, and month. I am just not happy with the outcome. It's not any shorter, it's actually more lines of code, and more complex than just validating them in the main function. And I already had all three valid inputs lists in the same place(the main function) I still go to just one place if I need to change any of the 3 lists of valid inputs , so changing in one place is not an additional benefit. What am I really gaining by doing this?

Comment: More code is not necessarily a bad thing, first and foremost you should be making your code understandable. You should strive for modular, reusable code and this is what my example is trying to show, I'm sorry that you're not happy with my approach, maybe you can post a gist to the code that you have ended up with and someone can take a look. 

What are you gaining? From my example do you mean? I was just answering your original question of how to stop the execution of a method in your program and how you can use return values to control the flow so that you could achieve the desired goal.

Comment: I should probably be more explicit and state that when I ask "what am I gaining?" I am not saying it in jist , I just understand that I am relatively ignorant and there's a good chance there's a gain/benefit I haven't considered . I just want to be 100% positive this is the best way. It seems to be, just holding out a little longer to make sure

Comment: I used a separate functions to validate each type. I tried to get around that by passing in 2 parameters. , one being the inputType, e.g. Company, and the 2nd parameter being input itself , e.g.  BVV, but I ran into the issue of how to make the function understand how to use the input type without a switch statement

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is with an exception:

```
class Parent
{
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var CompanyVar = comboBox1.Text;

            ValidateInput vi = new ValidateInput();
            vi.ValidateFinancialsInput(CompanyVar);
            //the rest of my code for the application is here
            //the rest ...
            //the rest...
        }
        catch (ValidationException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}

class ValidationException : Exception
{
    public ValidationException(string message) : base(message)
    {
    }
}

class ValidateInput
{
    public void ValidateFinancialsInput(string Co)
    {
        string[] validCompany = { "BVV", "LWDO" };
        if (validCompany.Contains(Co) == false)
        {
            throw new ValidationException("You have entered an invalid company.");
        }
    }
}
```

This will stop execution of `ValidateFinancialsInput` and in `button2_Click` move execution inside the `catch (ValidationException ex)` where you can decide what to do with the validation error

Comment: I saw this. I'm holding out , hoping there is something I can do without creating a 3rd class

Comment: You can throw a generic exception (replace ValidationException  with Exception) but this is not recommended.. don't be afraid to create new classes :)

Comment: Quick note, throwing and catching exception is really slow and should only be saved for well.... Exceptional circumstances, I would argue the only time you want to throw exceptions is when you can't recover from the scenario that the user has entered. Someone entering the wrong company name is not really exceptional, we can recover from that. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229009(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Debatable, I have used exception for validations, and have not had performance issues. The code can look cleaner and simpler, and there is no risk of someone forgetting to check the validation result (can happen more often then you might think). For this particular scenario, of a desktop app, throwing an exception should not have a noticeable perf penalty (when running without the debugger attached, exceptions are slower while debugging). This is also the opinion of others: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504302/is-it-a-good-or-bad-idea-throwing-exceptions-when-validating-data

Answer (score 1):

You have a class that it's whole purpose is to validate, So you could add a public method `IsValidated`

You could add much more with the class, for example have a list of all business rules it violates and return them through another method or property.

```
class ValidateInput
{
  public bool IsValidated {get; private set}
  public bool ValidateFinancialsInput(string Co)
  {
     string[] validCompany = { "BVV", "LWDO" };
     this.IsValidated = validCompany.Contains(Co)
  }
}
```

This class should only know about the validation process and should do nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options. It looks like you have buttons in your program so I would guess this is not a console application.  If you want the application to completely stop you can use `Application.Exit` or check out `Environment.Exit` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.exit(v=vs.110).aspx

However, I would suggest using exceptions so you do not terminate your entire program:

```
 try
        {
            var CompanyVar = comboBox1.Text;

            ValidateInput vi = new ValidateInput();
            vi.ValidateFinancialsInput(CompanyVar);
            //the rest of my code for the application is here
            //the rest ...
            //the rest...
        }
        catch (ValidationException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

 public void ValidateFinancialsInput(string Co)
    {
        string[] validCompany = { "BVV", "LWDO" };
        if (validCompany.Contains(Co) == false)
        {
            throw new ValidationException("You have entered an invalid company.");
        }
    }
```