# Is there a way to test error handling in ExpressJS with Mocha when using a custom error handler?

Tags: node.js, express, testing, mocha.js, integration-testing

Test

```
    it('should fail trying to GET bookmarks with false user id',async () => {
      try {
        const response = await request(app)
          .get(baseApiUrlUnderTest + 'false_user_id/bookmarks')
          .set('Authorization', bearerToken);
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e); //it doesn't reach this point
        expect(e.httpStatus).to.equal(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
      }
    });
```

The relevant part of the method under test:

```
/* GET bookmark of user */
personalBookmarksRouter.get('/', keycloak.protect(), wrapAsync(async (request, response) => {

  userIdTokenValidator.validateUserIdInToken(request);
 ...
}));
```

where `wrapAsync` makes sure the error is passed to the custom error handler:

```
let wrapAsync = function (fn) {
  return function(req, res, next) {
    // Make sure to `.catch()` any errors and pass them along to the `next()`
    // middleware in the chain, in this case the error handler.
    fn(req, res, next).catch(next);
  };
}
```

The `validateUserIdInToken` method which causes the method under test to throw an exception:

```
const AppError = require('../models/error');
const HttpStatus = require('http-status-codes');

let validateUserIdInToken = function (request) {
  const userId = request.kauth.grant.access_token.content.sub;
  if ( userId !== request.params.userId ) {
    throw new AppError(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, 'Unauthorized', ['the userId does not match the subject in the access token']);
  }
}

module.exports.validateUserIdInToken = validateUserIdInToken;
```

and the custom error handler in the root middleware:

```
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  if (res.headersSent) {
    return next(err)
  }
  if(err instanceof AppError) { //execution lands here as expected and the test stops...
    res.status(err.httpStatus);
    return res.send(err);
  } else {
    res.status(err.status || HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    res.send({
      message: err.message,
      error: {}
    });
  }

});
```

Comment: When you say, in your test "it doesn't reach this point", do you still get the `response`?

Comment: @laggingreflex you are right I didn't think to check that... The custom error handler sends a "valid" response back with the expected error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [@laggingreflex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1266650/laggingreflex)'s comment I missed debugging that the response actually returned with the expected status and error message

The adjusted test case now looks like this:

```
    it('should fail trying to GET bookmarks with false user id',async () => {
        const response = await request(app)
          .get(baseApiUrlUnderTest + 'false_user_id/bookmarks')
          .set('Authorization', bearerToken);

        expect(response.status).to.equal(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
    });
```

Comment: this was clearly pointed out my answer above: `result.should.have.status(401);`

Comment: I am sorry, maybe the question was not clear enough, but the emphasis was on how to throw the exception, use the custom error handler and test that - only the test needs adapting, everything else stays the same. Your proposal was to use a different approach...

Comment: You have been trying to `catch` an error in a 'try` statement around an ajax call on the client when it is being thrown/returned at the server. Your client test code would never have worked and I showed you that you should be testing for the status: `In your test, check the for status 401:` in your mocha tests.

Comment: Look the test before was exactly as you suggested in the answer, it is still present in the master branch - https://github.com/CodepediaOrg/bookmarks.dev-api/blob/171dddb8ac04bafd12ee36a3de81ab99a526a922/routes/users/personal-bookmarks.spec.js#L63. The code is also the same as you suggested.  But I wanted to refactor and did not know what I was doing false, before @laggginreflex pointed that out...

Comment: Can't comment on what was/wasn't in a repo somewhere and not going to check, But the question and snippet showed in your first code sample highlight the problem - same conclusion you have arrived at in your own answer. You have even said "I missed debugging that the response actually returned with the expected status and error message". Pretty odd behavior, but glad you have it sorted and all the best with your codepedia.

Comment: I really appreciate your input and before all it made my question whether generally I should throw exceptions on the server when validating inputs

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be approaching this incorrectly. Invalid auth should not raise errors in the app - it's not an error really, is a validation issue.

If the auth fails, simply send the relevant http error code - 401 back to the client.

```
res.send(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, 'a message if you want'); // 401
```

In your route handler:

```
personalBookmarksRouter.get('/', keycloak.protect(), wrapAsync(async (request, response) => {
  const userId = request.kauth.grant.access_token.content.sub;
  if ( userId !== request.params.userId ) {
     return response.send(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
  }

 ...
}));
```

In your test, check the for status 401:

```
chai.request(server)
    .get('/false_user_id/bookmarks')
    .end((err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            return callback(err);
        }

        result.should.have.status(401);
    });
```

Comment: This is actually exactly how the code looks right now -https://github.com/CodepediaOrg/bookmarks.dev-api/blob/171dddb8ac04bafd12ee36a3de81ab99a526a922/routes/users/personal-bookmarks.js#L129, but I wanted to consolidate the validation "errors" among others in a central place...

Comment: Now I am a little vexed whether this is a good thing to do (seeing also - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504302/is-it-a-good-or-bad-idea-throwing-exceptions-when-validating-data)... @laggingreflex pointed out what was I missing in this pursue

Comment: Put it this way, if you had a user submit some form data that needed to be validated, would use throw an exception if a field was not long enough? Hopefully not. The issue you raised in this question was about not `catching` the error on the client which we addressed in the answer. I had a brief look at that repo and really don't advise returning 404 errors if data is not found. Raise a new question about best practice for returning errors from the API and we can tackle some ideas there.

Comment: I totally see your point, and one big advantage would be also consolidation of validation breaches to send back. As for the auth part in this case it's truly "exceptional" if something like this happens... In this case there are both ways to an end (the api client will get the same response). How it's handled in the back-end code (readability, performance) plays a role for me.

Comment: You are now discussing a larger architectural decision that is far broader than your question which related to why your client request was not catching the error returned from the API: `console.log(e); //it doesn't reach this point`. Please rather close the question/accept the answer that explains the problem. Start a new architectural question so users use this question for future reference.